# Why does rotating one control point, affect the tilt of other control points of a bezier curve?

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

I am using a bezier curve to rig something. However when I rotate a singular or more control point by using an empty (Curve is hooked), other control point tilt (rotate, only tilt) with it . Furthermore, control points downwards the point I do want to rotate are unaffected whereas controlpoint upwards are affected.
How is this possible? And is there a way to prevent this?

I've included the blend. file here:

https://pasteall.org/blend/ac49ce2d8f13412dbe06429dfc82d465

Many thanks in advance!

Sander

-

[image: CurveProblem]